# C++ using callbacks of an arbitrary class with arbitrary parameters

Tags: c++, callback

I want to implement a class with a function able to callback to methods from the object that called that function, without information about it.

Imagine we want to callback to some methods of the class `Game` from `Library`:

```
void Game::display(string a) {
    cout << a << endl;
}

int Game::sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

void Game::start() {
    lib = new Library();
    lib->doSomething(/* somehow pass information about the functions*/);
}
```

And then:

```
void Library::doSomething(list_of_callbacks L /*or something like this*/) {
    L[0]("hi");  //L[0] is Game::display
    L[1](2,3);   //L[1] is Game::sum
}
```

It needs to work not just with `Game`, but with any class. The methods we want to call back may need access to the object's attributes (so not necessarily static).

I'm kinda new to `C++`; I've been searching on the topic for hours now but in most cases the return type or the parameters of all the callback methods are the same. I've tried to get something working with templates and `std::function` / `std::bind` but unsuccessfully.

Thanks, and sorry if I didn't make myself clear enough, it's my first post around here.

EDIT:

The `doSomething` function is going to be generated (translated) by an external tool, which has information about the list of functions (like, the function in L[0] takes these parameters or these others, etc).

If what I'm asking can't be done in C++, isn't there ***any*** other way to achieve the same goal? Being able to get information from the caller?

Comment: How do you expect your doSomething() function to know that L[0] accepts a string, while L[1] accepts two ints?  This is sort of necessary to avoid passing a string to a function expecting ints, or vice versa.

Comment: I don't know what kind of library you're building but you could use a Pattern.  Start with a simple base class, requiring basic methods, if you need access to attributes define getters and return them as Objects, who knows.  Designing is fun!